# Webkit CSS absolute positioning bug?

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-position

I've got an image that I'm scaling to act as a background with another image in a div absolutely positioned over it, as such:

```
<div class="item">
    <img class="item_frame" src="...">
    <div class="item_contents">
        <img src="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddles :

- [CSS bug demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7Tqa/4/)
- [Jquery demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7Tqa/6/) - same behavior after dom manipulation

In webkit broswers I'm seeing very funky rendering where the background image is offset and seems to float outside it's parent container.  If I right click to inspect the element, the browser comes to and redraws the elements appropriately.

- Win64 Firefox 3.6.3 is buggy
- Win64 Chrome 15.x is buggy
- Win64 IE9 ... actually is the only browser that displays it correctly

The markup here is pretty hacky anyway to accommodate dynamic image loading/resizing/cropping so I've got a few ideas on other ways to work around this I can try.

Am I missing something or is this a webkit bug?

Comment: I don't answer the question but can't you use a pattern as background?

Comment: Why do you have the background image as a 'normal' image in stead of the background of the div?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- the background is a non-tiling image that needs to stretch.  background-size would work except we need to support IE8 (http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size).  It might have to be tables :(

Comment: @MatTheCat & @ PH : does that mean you saw the same behaviour?

Comment: @RSG yep too, chrome 15(.0.874.120)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is a bug; but you can try adding left and top values to the .item_frame css style to fix it:

```
.item_frame {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Updated CSS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Tqa/7/

Updated jQuery Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Tqa/8/

I hope this helps!